# How to play parkour/adventure maps with a friend?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've downloaded and am playing a Minecraft parkour/adventure map. How can I get my friend to join the map and play with me?

Answer (score 3):

You have 4 options now.

1. Get your friend on a PC with Minecraft that is in your home, or if he has Minecraft on his laptop, tell him to bring it. You need 2 computers running Minecraft on the same network (LAN) and then choose 'Open to LAN'. All computers on your Local Area Network (LAN) will be able to join it. Here's a link to it:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_LAN_world

"A LAN game is only accessible to other people in your local network (e.g. just the people also connected to your router/switch are able to connect to you) unless you setup port forwarding on your router, then people can direct connect with your IP and port. (ex. 123.45.67.89:43787)"

2. If you  haven yet used Realms, you can get a free 1 month trial, so get it set up and get your buddy to join.
3. Get your own server! Yes, it may be pricey but it will work, and if its for just you and your buddy you can get it as low as 0.5$ per month, but that is gonna require setup and experience with plugins etc...
4. If you have a static IP address, you can host your own server! I do not recommend this, as it uses up your CPU and RAM in order to run. You also have to port-forward your IP.

   [Instructables' guide to setting up a Server](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Your-Own-Minecraft-Server-for-Free/)

   [How to port-forward](http://m.wikihow.com/Portforward-Minecraft)

Comment: This is a good start, but you may want to add some additional information to option 1. Telling the asker to just Google their question defeats the purpose of our website. Try doing some research on your own, and post the useful links you find as sources, as well as citing information from those websites in your answer, if possible.

Comment: Its not really a thing to google, because it doesent need any further info. But thanks for the suggestion, i'll keep that in mind!

Comment: Well, telling me that "there's nothing to Google" after editing out the part where you told the user to Google something is kinda weird, but I can let it slide.

Comment: I did it kinda cause you told me it would be better. I agree, cause your suggestion made the answer better, but LAN is not a thing that really needed the link.